# View to specyfic Group Users in Sharepoin

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, groups

I want to ask how to do a View for specyfic Grop from Users.

I have got 5 Group, and I want to do a View for specyfic Group of Users. Administrators should see all elements, and the difrent users should see a less of column elements.

Comment: This view you want to do in a certain list native?

Comment: Yes in custom list